# GWT GIN circular dependency

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

Here is an example that I have -

```
public class GinDemoPresenter implements Presenter {

   private View view;

   @Inject
   public GinDemoPresenter (View view) {
      this.view = view;
   }
   ....
}

public class GinDemoView implements View {

   private Presenter presenter;

   @Inject
   public GinDemoView(Presenter presenter) {
      this.presenter = presenter;
   }
   ....
}
```

During compilation I see this -

```
...
Cycle detected in the dependency graph.  Consider using a Provider?
...
```

Can someone provide an example of how to resolve circular dependency in GIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be following pattern:

```
public class GinDemoPresenter implements Presenter {

   private View view;

   @Inject
   public GinDemoPresenter (View view) {
      this.view = view;
      view.setPresenter(this);
   }
   ....
}

public class GinDemoView implements View {

   private Presenter presenter;

   public GinDemoView() {
   }

   public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter){
      this.presenter = presenter;
   }
   ....
}
```

I would suggest to decouple the `View` from the `Prensenter`, by introducing interfaces.

Comment: But when I do try to use the view i.e. View view = new GinDemoView(); The presenter won't be injected automatically right?

Comment: As soon as you `new` an object, you're giving up using dependency injection (unless you later explicitly inject members)

Comment: Sorry I meant to say, if I do something like - Injector.getView() (which returns the GinDemoView). Basically, what I want to do is, by injecting view, I want to inject the presenter into the view.

Comment: But you cannot Inject an instance of A.class into B.class AND inject a instance of B.class into A.class at the same time. This can also not be done by hand, withut DI.

Comment: This is why the error suggests using a Provider.  You can safely inject Provider<Presenter> and Provider<View> into each other's constructors; if you invoke them inside the constructors, you'll go into infinite recursion land, but if you store Provider as field and defer access, you can safely break the recursion chain.

Comment: If you think about it, with your constructor's as is, how would it be possible to create either object without DI?  Dependency injection must still obey the laws of linear execution; it's just generating the wiring code for you.  If you can't code the situation yourself, it's also impossible for DI to code it for you.